# Unable to access the real page source code

Tags: python, web-scraping

This is not one of those standard issues about javascript modifying some parts of page source which become hidden after you *right click > view page source*. My problem is different.

Actually I am able to see the whole html code when I *right click > view page source* but when I try to read this url via BeautifulSoup, xml.parser, or even open it with mechanize, at this point the page becomes kind of different and is missing the important contents.

The only way I can get down this real html code is to manually copy/pase whole content and save as a file. When I do it automatically with python the content also changes.

Essentially the site is in html, but saw there some javascript,flash and ajax code too.

Have you guys any ideas what can be done? I know it might be hard to figure out without actually seeing the source code but I guess I'd be better off not posting the page url I'm scraping from.

Comment: Have you tried to use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-spidermonkey to execute the JS code in the page, before fetching the resulting DOM?

Comment: No, I have not actually. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually due to the page sending you a different response due to a different Referrer or UserAgent header.

Try setting the user agent by setting the headers to Firefox for example

```
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1"
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }
```

Comment: Actually I use this in my code and it does not do its job here.

Comment: @nutship What about setting referrer? Assuming you're using urllib2 have you tried to download the page, save it to a file and try opening it?

Comment: Yes, I did. Still the part of the code needed is hidden. As I said, the only working solution is if I copy/pase it manually and save in a file.

Comment: What if you go to the browser and disable JavaScript? Does that also prevent the correct result? If so, you might need something like Selenium that actually drives a browser instead of an HTTP request.